# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection on Talend

Tags: oracle, esb, talend

i have this error on my Talend JOB :

Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection

On my local talend it works good, but not on a remote server.

Regards.

Comment: Presumably, you have to put the Oracle JDBC driver somewhere on your remote server. Have you checked the Talend documentation? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18875923/610979 looks similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ojdbc lib has to be put on the lib/ext folder of your runtime.